# Webp image not loading on iphone's chrome, safari and firefox

Tags: html, image, webp

I have two images in my html page that are of webp file type.

```
<img src="./assets/beros-capak.webp" class="article-image" />
<img src="./assets/mapa.webp" class="article-image" />
```

[image]

But, as you can see in the image above, the first webp image is not loaded and the other is loading fine.

I have tested it on chrome, firefox and safari on iphone, and they are all not loading the first image, while both on android and mac pc load both images with no errors.
Why is that?

Comment: You say that Chrome, Firefox and Safari on an iPhone are all not loading the first image. But are they all loading the second? That is not shown in the image you've included.

Comment: Have you been able to sort this out? Having a similar issue. webp image loads in desktop, but not in mobile. In Desktop inspector for the type is seen as webp , but in mobile it is XML.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of iOS.

All browsers on iOS use WebKit so they are all subject to the same compatibility issues as Safari.

According to https://caniuse.com/webp, WebP is supported on iOS 14 and up.

Comment: Firefox is using Safari's engine, but Chrome has it's own, I think. I don't know since when, but I now see issues in Chrome on my iPad that I don't see in Safari. And their settings are the same.